# A claim regarding Perott's proof of infinitude of primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

The following is a picture from 'History of the theory of numbers, volume l Divisibility and Primality' by L. E. Dickson. Dickson wrote J. perott's proof of 'Infinitude of primes'. The first line does not seem correct to me.If $n=2$ and $N=3$ leads to contradiction. It seems Dickson did some mistake. Is not it?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: well $2^2>3-3/4-3/9>3*(2-pi^2/6)>1.$ Either way, if it is the case, what does that matter? Just take $N>3.$ Still the theorem holds.

Comment: I believe the intent was $\textit {at most } 2^n$.  After all, many of the products defined by subsets of those primes will be greater than $N$.  For $N=12$, say, we have $n=5$ but there are obviously not $32$ square free integers $≤12$. Of course, that just makes the argument even stronger.

Comment: As a general comment:  if you insist on holding old mathematics writing to the same standards of exactness and precision that we prefer today, you are likely to be frustrated.  People often wrote casually (assuming, I suppose, that only other experts would be interested) and their readers are often called upon to fill in missing details.

Comment: O really... actually I am a beginner.. thanks for the information.

Comment: Anyway ..it had nothing to do with precision for at least to me. I didn't really understand what he meant. That is why I posted it here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant at most $2^n$.  Using the primes $p_1,..., p_2$ the squarefree numbers that can be formed are just numbers formed by either including or not including $p_k$ as a single power factor.  And there are $2^n$ such numbers.  However it is a dead *certainty* many of those will be greater than $N$ if $p_n$ is the largest prime less than $N$. In fact Bertrands lemma *assures* the $N< 2p_n < p_{n-1}p_n < ... <\prod p_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

If $p_1, ...., p_n$ are the primes less than $N$ then the square free numbers that can be made with these prime factors can be formed by taking a product that can be made by either including a $p_k$ as a factor ... or not including it.  So there are $2^n$ square free numbers that can be made.

(Example.  For $p_1,p_2, p_3$ the $2^3 =8$ square free numbers that can be formed are $1, p_1=2; p_2= 3; p_3 = 5; p_1p_2 = 6; p_1p_3=10; p_2p_3 =15; p_1p_2p_3=30$.)

But many, maybe even *most* will be Larger than $N$.  If $p_3 = 5 \le N < p_4 =7$ then *three* of those $8$ squarefree numbers are more than $N$

Indeed by Bertrands Postulate (which is hard to prove and maybe even unproven in Dickson's day) If $p_n \le N < p_{n+1}$ then $2p_n > N$.

So the statement that the squarefree numbers less than or equal to $N$ being $2^n$ is *certainly* false.  But the number of square free numbers being *less* than $2^n$ is certainly true.

And that is enough for the rest of the proof.

Comment: Chebyshev proved Bertrand's Postulate in 1850 (or maybe slightly before, he presented his Memoire to the Imperial Academy in 1850), Dickson's History is from the early $20^{\text{th}}$ century ($10$s to $20$s, I think), so even the PNT was available to Dickson. For $N$ not too small, only a negligible fraction of the $2^{\pi(N)} = N^{O\bigl(\frac{N}{(\log N)^2}\bigr)}$ squarefree products of primes $\leqslant N$ are themselves $\leqslant N$, so the "maybe" caveat is only needed for small $N$.

Comment: Well, okie-dokie then.